# Image css layers

Tags: css, image, layer

Is there a way to make images of one page become in different layers so they can move around without affecting other images/elements? I tried to use z-index it worked but the weird thing that the page becomes more taller and when I use jQuery.position.left/top I get different position than the one the image is on, for example: I use jquery.draggable(); to move images above each other when I check the source code for the page I find the image on position for ex. (422, -330), but when I use jquery.position.left + jquery.position.top the position is (455, 313).

Can anybody explain why this is happeneing? and help me to fix it?

Thanx in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent container for the 'stacked' images needs to have position: relative set to it, and then the images can have absolute position.

If this is going to be something you do throughout your site, a reusable pattern would be to have a container element (which has position: relative), and then all the images can be stacked inside of it.

Comment: Hi, I was set up each image to have a span tag with position relative, now I changed that to make the position of the main container (which includes all the stacked images), when I use jquery().position.left or top I get undefined. Please advice.

Comment: hi again, I figured out why undefined, but the problem stays the same when checking an element position inside a container with relative position it gives me a wrong reading => element with (233, -546) when checked by jquery().position().left and top (288, 86). Please help